# VBA EXCEL: how to sum all the count values?

Tags: vba, excel

```
 arr1 = Array("chocolate","icecream","sweet")

For Each elem In arr1 '<--| loop through 1st array list
                fooditem = fooditem + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "sugar", .Columns(20), "yes", .Columns(31), elem)
            Next elem
```

Here, the output is only showing result of either equal to chocolate or icecream or sweet. but I want to add the total counts.
ie the total count should be equal to icecream + chocolate + sweet.
*for example in excel it is =sum(countif(........))*

how to write this in vba??

any help is really appreciated.
thank you so much.

Comment: The code you have above seems to work for me.  It counts and sums all three.  Why not use the `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"sugar",T:T,"yes",AE:AE,{"chocolate","icecream","sweet"})` formula? which also works.

Comment: Can u tell me the VBA function for this?

Comment: Your loop works just fine, I have tested it and got the correct answer.  Not sure what else you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Application.SumIf function, like so:

```
Application.SumIf(Range("B2:B4"), Array("chocolate", "icecream", "sweet"), Range("C2:C4"))
```

But, both the first and last argument must be range objects. The first is the range you're searching through and the last is the range of the corresponding sums. The fact that the corresponding sums are all equal to 1 in this case doesn't matter--it still has to be a range object (so the 1s have to be written somewhere in your worksheet).

Is that close to what you were looking for? thanks